# Why am I Strange Output when using printf in C?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, string-literals, pointer-arithmetic

I've been working on this problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf(5 + "Good Morning ");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this print Morning?

Any explanations?

Comment: Hint: `"Good Morning "` - is a *pointer* to a memory location containing the string. The rest is a pointer arithmetics.

Comment: The programme starts reading the char array at position 5. `char *p` -> `5 + p` is equivalent to `&p[5]`

Comment: Will it help if you rewrite it as `char *p = "Good Morning ";  printf(p + 5);`?

Comment: What do you think this prints `printf(0 + "Good Morning ");`

Answer (score 2):

In this call of printf

```
printf(5 + "Good Morning ");
```

there is used the string literal `"Good Morning "` that has the type `char[14]`. Used in the expression `5 + "Good Morning "` it is converted to a pointer to its first character and has the type `char *`.

So due to the pointer arithmetic the expression having the type `char *` points to the element of the string literal at the position equal to `5` (positions start from 0). That is it points to the substring `"Morning "` of the original string literal. And that substring is outputted.

You could equivalently rewrite the call the following way to make it more clear

```
char * literal = "Good Morning ";
printf( literal + 5 );
```

or

```
char * literal = "Good Morning ";
printf( &literal[5] );
```

or even like

```
printf( &"Good Morning "[5] );
```

Here is a demonstrative program but instead of `printf` I am using `puts`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( puts( i + "Good Morning " ) != 1 ) i++;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Good Morning 
ood Morning 
od Morning 
d Morning 
 Morning 
Morning 
orning 
rning 
ning 
ing 
ng 
g
```