# How to explain the output of this program in C?

Tags: c, printf

I've been working on this problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%c", "abcdefgh"[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives e as the output, however I couldn't understand that how an array named "abcdefgh" with 4 elements is getting printed.

In nutshell, please tell me how this program works.

Comment: Does it help if you rewrite your code like this: `char *text = "abcdefgh"; printf("%c", text[4]);` ?

Comment: This is very similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013319/why-am-i-strange-output-when-using-printf-in-c). Please try harder extrapolating the answer to this one.

Comment: In a nutshell, you better read a book about C. If you want to learn C by asking questions on [so], chances are that C will be out of fashion when you master it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, a string is sequence of character terminated by null character (\0).

When you declaring a string:

```
"abcdefgh"
```

it's actually:

```
char array[9] = "abcdefgh";
```

and you are accessing 5th character from the array, since array is 0-based data-structure.

you are actually doing:

```
printf("%c",array[4]);
```

therefore, it points to 5-th character in array;

```
a b c d e f g h
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

The string `"abcdefgh"` doesn't have 4 elements.  It's an array with 9 elements (the characters plus the null terminator, and square brackets are the array subscript operator.

So `"abcdefgh"[4]` is getting the element at index 4 from `"abcdefgh"` which is `'e'`.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal like `"abcdefgh"` is an array expression - its type is "9-element array of `char`" (8 characters plus the string terminator).  The subscript operator works on it like any other array expression, so `"abcdefgh"[4]`" evaluates to the 5th element of the string, which is the character `'e'`.